# Multiple insert statements in a single command

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I was struggling with my code. When I try to execute insert statement and stored procedure at once, the textbox value for the stored procedure appears empty when stored to database. But when I execute only the stored procedure, textbox value has a data and stores to database.

What did I miss? This my code:

```
private void recorduserlog()
        {           
            sqlcon.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "userlogs";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", Main.userid));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fullname", Main.passname));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@activitydetails", txtfullname.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userform", 1));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datelog", DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss")));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcon.Close();
        }

private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (txtusername.Text != "" && txtaccesscode.Text != "" && txtfullname.Text != "" && cmbaccessleve.Text != "")  //validating the fields whether the fields or empty or not  
            {
                if (txtaccesscode.Text.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == txtconfirm.Text.ToString().Trim().ToLower()) //validating Password textbox and confirm password textbox is match or unmatch    
                {
                    string UserName = txtusername.Text;
                    string Password = adduser.Encrypt(txtaccesscode.Text.ToString());   // Passing the Password to Encrypt method and the method will return encrypted string and stored in Password variable.  
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.myconnectionstring);
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into endusers(usern,passw,fullname,accesslevel,stats)values('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "','" + txtfullname.Text + "','" + ssfapclass + "',1)", conn);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();
                    sqlcon.Dispose();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Created a User Account for '" + txtfullname.Text + "'.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Close();
                    recorduserlog();        
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Access Code and Confirmation Code doesn't match!.. Please Check..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);  //showing the error message if password and confirm password doesn't match  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields!..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);  //showing the error message if any fields is empty  
            }
        }
    }
```

One thing more, the two SQL queries use the same TEXTBOX value as parameters.

Comment: In `btnsave_Click` shouldn't you use the new sqlconnection you just created (which is`conn`) instead of `sqlcon`?

Comment: Your INSERT should be using Parameters like your stored procedure or else you're at risk for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @xoxel i declared (sqlcon)  as public connection because when i try to run the code at the same time, it gives me an error. so i declared two connection for the insert statement and stored procedure.

Comment: @JansenMalaggay yes, and this is exactly because i assumed you did that that i'am pointing that out, you are still using the same connection for both functions. At least seems like it. Anyway if you are not using `conn` you should probably remove it, because you actually never use it

Comment: oh! i'm sorry, i edited the code. i actually used the (conn) connection. But still its not working. as you can see in the code, they both use the "txtfullname.text" to insert some data in the database, only one statement is successfull, the stored procedure does not get the value of the textbox. how is it?

Comment: You should *not* store SqlConnction as a field or property. They should be local to the method where they're being used. Create as late as possible, dispose as early as possible. They should be in using statements.

Comment: @mason oh sorry bro, i'm just a beginner and i would welcome any of your idea you could share. i store my connection string so i can easily change if the project is copied to another computer. So, if its wrong, i would appreciate your suggestion and sample code if you would mind. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for some clarification on how to handle SqlConnection, I'll try to break it down for you.

A SqlConnection uses unmanaged resources (open socket connections to a database server). The garbage collector only frees up memory, not unmanaged resources. Therefore, when the garbage collector removes SqlConnection from memory, it can leave the dangling connections. Over time, this can exhaust the number of connections to your database server and lead to difficult to diagnose issues.

In .NET, we have a pattern for dealing with unmanaged resources. Objects that deal with unmanaged resources will implement the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. Any IDisposable objects should be dealt with carefully. *Most of the time* (there's a few exceptions) an IDisposable object should be disposed of within a `finally` block, or created within a `using` statement. Either of these patterns will ensure that the unmanaged resources get disposed of properly.

[SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) implements IDisposable (because it inherits from System.Data.Common.DbConnection). Since it's a good idea to have a dedicated class for handling database interaction, this often leaves us with code that looks like this:

```
public class SqlServerDatabaseRepository
{
    readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlServerDatabaseRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void ExecuteUserLogs(string userId, /* additional parameters */)
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
        {
            //use your connection here to execute your command
        }   //here the connection falls out of scope so the using statement will handle disposing it for you
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro @mason. well i guess i need to do more readings.. one last question for you bro, Am i going to include this code you provided in my USERFORM or i'm going to make a class?

Comment: @JansenMalaggay Your forms are UI code. They should have no awareness of how the data layer is implemented. So you're going to need a new class. And ideally an entirely new class library (a new project)

Comment: wow.. it seems like i have a long way to go.. well i guess i need a teacher bro.. can you share me some websites where i can read more on this..thanks bro, i appreciate much of your help.

Comment: Nope, nothing specific. You'll just have to find some good books or web resources. I do highly recommend watching [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) though.

Comment: How do i call this Class to execute queries in windows forms command button?

Comment: @Jansen you would create an instance of the repository and then call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will shut down the application

```
this.Close();
```

As stated in a comment you are not using

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.myconnectionstring);
```

You should but using `using` blocks